# How to use jquery in html to send POST request and receive word by word from python app

Tags: python

I hope someone will help me with a example code:

I have a test.html and flask app.py on my website https://example.com/test.html

when I load the page https://example.com/test.html from browser, it will send a POST with a string to app.py. App.py will explode that string in words and send back via SSE to test.html word by word (stream).

test.html will receive word by word from app.py and append them to the div id=output word by word.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your question?  Where is your attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: what prevents you from getting all words at once and then output them word by word in javascript? Handling a stream through standard XHR will be a lot more complex

Comment: this is only an simple example to understand how to handle a stream. My project is more complex and require this handling :(